# Only Seen From Above

Tags: riddle, word

No matter how far you look up, you will barely see me.

Only those above me can see me.

I pour what the above has to offer.

In speeches, I am suspicious.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to suggest the word is

> Nose

---

*No matter how far you look up, you will barely see me.*

> We can always see our nose in our very peripheral vision, and our ability to view it doesn't matter how far up we look.

*Only those above me can see me.*

> Only our eyes ("those" above our nose) can see our nose.

*I pour what the above has to offer.*

> Our eyes offer up tears to our nose, which pours out as water, snot, and other unpleasantness.

*In speeches, I am suspicious.*

> "Keep it under your nose", tapping on the nose, wrinkling of the nose, are all indications of suspicion or covertness. It's also possible to be nosy (i.e. nose-y, as a figure of speech), which follows from suspicion of others.

Comment: Really nice interpretation. However, that is not the intended answer :)

Answer (score 5):

I think the word is,

> Shadow

---

*No matter how far you look up, you will barely see me.*

> Shadows on Earth are formed **down** as the source of light, the Sun is above it. So we can't see them above us.

*Only those above me can see me.*

> We can see the shadow only if we are above it.

*I pour what the above has to offer.*

> Shadow is the silhouette of the object above it and it is formed/poured down.

*In speeches, I am suspicious.*

> Here **shady**  = suspicious

Comment: If the shadow is on the wall (created by say a light bulb) then you do not have to be above it to see it. Just a thought.

Comment: The 4th hint has the answer I was looking for, it is a good interpretation, however it isn't the exact answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the word is,

> Eyes

---

*No matter how far you look up, you will barely see me.*

> We cannot see our eyes if we try to look up.

*Only those above me can see me.*

> Only taller people can see the eyes of ones who are shorter than them.

*I pour what the above has to offer.*

> Tears pour down as offered by the person above.

*In speeches, I am suspicious.*

> **suspicious eyes** is commonly used for a doubtful/suspecting person.

Comment: This is the closest interpretation so far, though not the intended solution... nice try :)